# Estimate error bound

Tags: linear-algebra

If $||A||<1$, and I want to solve $(I-A)\vec x=\vec b$ using the Neumann series iteration, which is
\begin{align*}
    \vec x_0 &= \vec 0,\\
    \vec x_j &= A\vec x_{j-1} + b, \quad j = 1,2,3\ldots.
\end{align*}
How do I find the error bound of $\|\vec x- \vec x_k\|$, where $\vec x$ is the exact solution and $\vec x_k$ is the solution at step $k$ of this iteration involving the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes the source and motivation of the problem, your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact solution is $(I-A)^{-1} b=\sum_{k=0} ^{\infty} A^{k}b$. Since $x_n=b+Ab+\cdots +A^{n-1} b$ we get $\|x-x_n\| \leq \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \|A^{k}b\|\leq  \frac {\|A\|^{k} } {1-\|A\|} \|b\|$.